# Linearly independent vectors in normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Considering the sequence {$\textbf{x}_k\}_{k=1}^{N} $ in a normed vector space $X$. Assuming a constant $\alpha>0$ such that

$\alpha \sum_{k=1}^{N} |c_k|^2 \leq || \sum_{k=1}^{N} c_k \textbf{x}_k ||^2 $

is true for all $c_k$. How can I show that the vectors {$\textbf{x}_k\}_{k=1}^{N} $ are linearly independent ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the vectors are linearly dependent. Then there exist $c_1,\dots,c_N$ *not all* $0$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^Nc_k\mathbf{x_k}=0
$$
By the assumption,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N|c_k|^2>0
$$